# A participle construction?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction

Excerpt from ‘The Proclamation of the Irish Republic, 1916’

‘The Republic guarantees religious and civil liberty, equal rights and equal opportunities to all its citizens, and declares its resolve to pursue the happiness
and prosperity of the whole nation and of all its parts, cherishing all of the children of the nation equally.’

Is the last part a participle construction?

If so, does this sentence mean something like
'The republic guarantees ... and declares ... , and it always cherishes the children equally.’ ?

Comment: Not really. More like, "to pursue ... all its parts, **by** cherishing all of the children."

Answer (score 0):

> cherishing all of the children of the nation equally

The above is a gerund-participial phrase (or clause as some call it).

We often use such constructions to

> say information in a more economical way.  They are formed using present participles [nowadays called gerund-participles] ...

That phrase means the same as the clause

> and it cherishes all of the children of the nation equally

The OP's example is hence equivalent to

> The Republic **guarantees** religious and civil liberty ... and **declares** its resolve ... **and cherishes** all ...

[Bullet 3 of the 4 under **Present participle clauses**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/c1-grammar/participle-clauses) gives the function applicable to the OP's example:

> To talk about an action that happened at the same time as another action